# declaring a function virtual slows it down; alternatives?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `WorkerA` that works on one image format (let's just call it A, it's rather non-standard). The class has been working well:

```
class WorkerA
{
public:
    void Setup()
    {
          //some stuff specific to format A
     }

     void MainTask()
     {
          //some algorithm that calls GetPixel() a lot
     }
    //...

protected:     
     int GetPixel(int x, int y)
     {
          int value;
          //value = ... (gets pixel value in format A)
          return value;
     }

     unsigned char * pBitmapA;
     //...
};
```

Now I need another class that works on image format B.  `MainTask` and a few other functions are the same as `WorkerA`, but the remaining function needs different implementations.  Unsure of the best practice in this scenario, I hacked together something like the following:

```
class WorkerB : public WorkerA
{
public:
    void Setup()
    {
          //some stuff specific to format B
    }
    //... (other functions. MainTask not re-implemented.)

protected:     
     virtual int GetPixel(int x, int y)
     {
          int value;
          //value = ... (gets pixel value in format B)
          return value;
     }

     unsigned char ** pBitmapB;     //different format than pBitmapA
};
```

By this point, I also made `WorkerA::GetPixel` virtual, to get the correct polymorphic behavior when I call `WorkerB::MainTask`.  However, this one change caused `WorkerA::MainTask` to run 50% longer than before -- something I really need to avoid.

My question is: how should I rearrange these 2 classes so that there's as little duplicated code as possible, without the speed penalty?  I can completely rewrite WorkerA and WorkerB if necessary (although preferrably I can keep WorkerA's existing interface), but I can't change the image formats.

Comment: Can either GetPixel() be static, or do they need access to class members/functions?

Comment: Does the code that uses the worker really doesn't know the workers actual type? Can't you use [static polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Static_polymorphism)?

Comment: For a start I wouldn't make B inherit from A unless B was kind of an A. I'd create a base Image class with pure virtual functions and make A and B inherit from that.

Comment: We need more details about the problem.  Like how are WorkerA and WorkerB being called.  And what exactly is the difference between the two GetPixel methods.  You can't 'just' get rid of virtual methods, but depending on how they're being used, it's possible they're not necessary.

Comment: Probably, most of the time is spent in function calls, virtual or not.  Try tagging the getter and setter functions as `inline` and raise the optimization level.

Comment: @dif: they both need to be members.  They access the member pBitmapA/pBitmapB arrays.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, you can mark a virtual function as `inline` but it won't do any good. Anyplace where you need virtual behavior you'll go through the overhead of a vtable.

Comment: @StoryTeller, sashang, QuestionC: The caller knows the type of worker. "B inherits A" was what I came up with at the time, but it quickly "felt" wrong, which is what brought me here looking for alternatives.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I tried `virtual`, `inline`, and no modifier.  `inline` was a couple % faster than no modifier, but `virtual` added a definite and reproducible slowdown.

Comment: These tricks will gain you negligible time.  The most impressive speed gain is to perform everything in blocks, as Mark Ransom stated in his answer below.  For example, one call to get a vector of 256 pixels rather than 256 calls to get 1 pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally any imaging code that makes a call for each pixel is going to be slow. If you can, refactor the code so it works with a much larger block, perhaps a raster line at a time.

If you can determine which class to use at compile time rather than run time, you can use the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to eliminate the overhead of a virtual call.

Comment: I've heard of the CRTP technique before but didn't really understand what it solves.  I'll definitely read through it again. Thanks!

regarding refactoring: I think I will eventually, for the same reasons you mentioned. But at this point I want to be sure I get correct results with the new WorkerB (with reasonable performance), before trying to optimize.

Comment: @martin_ljchan, that was my point - the way the code is structured now, "reasonable performance" may not be achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but there are themes here worth following.

1. GetPixel() is a notoriously bad thing from a performance point of view. Seriously consider using algorithms that do not require a heavy dependence on this. Maybe convert it to inline or template or macro if it really has to be.
2. Are you sure about the benchmarking? The inherent overhead from a virtual function call is a couple of machine instructions, which would not ordinarily cause such a severe impact. Are you sure there isn't something else going on here?
3. Do you really need virtual? Inheritance is a solution to many problems, not all of which require virtual functions and dynamic binding. Perhaps you can reorganise your code to use static inheritance or templating, at least for a good part of what you need, and avoid the virtual call to GetPixel() entirely.

If you have more info please edit your question accordingly.